# How do I type a vinculum?

Tags: linux, input

I am attempting to draw a [vinculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)) over a 3.

What I tried: Ctrl + Shift + u to enter unicode, then entering 0305, then enter. I get this: `̅`

The issue is I cannot center a digit centered under that character. E.g. if I put the three before, I get `3̅`, vice versa `̅3`. The only option that looks decent has been to put it under both `3̅3`.

I don't know, maybe my font rendering is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: if I type `Ctrl+Shift+u` `0` `3` `0` `5` `space` `3`.
But only only **one** `space` or `enter` between the unicode codepoint for the combiner (0305) and the character you want to combine it with.

Answer (score -1):

It's your font rendering. It works fine for me. This is what worked for me "̅3" (Sorry for such a late response)

Comment: what font do you use?